# QUndostack remove item above current index

Tags: qt, stack

I have a QUndoStack that looks like

```
2 - something (active)
1 - something
0 - bottom of stack
```

Two situations are possible now: 
I:
open a dialog which pushes several things to the stack merged as one and  click "accept", the stack looks like this:

```
3 - dialog done (active)
2 - something
1 - something
0 - bottom of stack
```

II:
open a dialog which pushes several things to the stack merged as one and  click "cancel", the stack looks like this:

```
3 - dialog done
2 - something (active)
1 - something
0 - bottom of stack
```

(I) is ok, (II) is technicaly also ok, but I want (3) be gone:

```
2 - something (active)
1 - something
0 - bottom of stack
```

As soon the user does something else the stack looks fine again:

```
3 - new thing done (active)
2 - something 
1 - something
0 - bottom of stack
```

But I want to remove the command entirely from the stack if the user pushed cancel, the command is never used again and only confuses the user if present. The stack should look like before, as nothing happend.

I found

```
void QUndoCommand::setObsolete(bool obsolete)
```

which i assume is the right command to tell the stack to remove the item, documentation says:

```
  If a command is set obsolete 
  and the clean index is greater than or equal to the current command index, 
  then the clean index will be reset 
  when the command is deleted from the stack.
```

but I wonder how to access the merged commands? 
I am afraid

```
const QUndoCommand *QUndoCommand::child(int index) const
const QUndoCommand *QUndoStack::command(int index) const
```

are not the right ways to go, since they are given back as const and because of the documentation warnings.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundostack.html
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundocommand.html#setObsolete

Comment: Why is command (3) on the undo stack in the first place if it was never applied?

Comment: @MartinHennings: The dialog lets the user apply several values, but if he decides to cancel at the last step, I want to rollback everything without saving a lot of temporary values in beetween.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are using the topmost command as a 'preview' to show what accepting the open dialog would do.

In this case, and if I also understand Qt's documentation correctly, you should `setObsolete(true)` the topmost ('preview') command **and then** undo it. That should delete it from the stack.

The merged command is (as I interpret your question) the complete effect that accepting the dialog would have, so this entire command is obsolete.

Comment: In the dialog creation of new objects and manipulation of current and new objects is possible, "modify old1, modify old3, add new object as o4, modify o4, delete old1" should be doable, and also not having any effect if rolled back. Therefor I used qundostack::beginmacro()  und endmacro() in dialog::reject()/accept(). There is no "command" (since they are hidden by the macro).